# fill object with linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having some problems when trying to cast the result of a linq query to a individual object. I am using the following method to return a `CodPromocion` but it is returning an empty result.

```
public CodPromocion MostrarCodigoPromoByID(int id)
{
    LaFidelitasExamenFinalEntities db = new LaFidelitasExamenFinalEntities();
    CodPromocion codpromo = new CodPromocion();
    try
    {
         codpromo =(CodPromocion)db.CodPromocions.Where(a => a.ID == id);

        return codpromo;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

As you can se the method does what it has to do but it returns empty. I already checked that there is a record with that ID.

Comment: This code will throw an exception. Where doesn't return a single object but an IEnumerable of them

Comment: I think if you stepped through the code you'd see the issue (returning an IQueryable<CodPromicion> where you'd need to convert that to what you want ( IQueryable<T>.FirstOrDefault() perhaps)

Comment: @Steve Wrong, it returns an `IQueryable` of them, not an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I tried to stopped the running by adding breakpoint strategically but visual studio didn`t stop the solution

Answer (score 0):

To return a single object from your Entity you should use FirstOrDefault

```
codpromo = db.CodPromocions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
```

and you don't need to call new to initialize *codpromo*
Of course, if there is no entity with that particular id passed you will still get a *null* result.
Final note, if you don't do anything with the exception but just rethrow it then remove the try/catch

Comment: Thank Steve I am gonna try it

Comment: Steve it is working I would like to run a some more tests what I dont understand is why I should use FirstOrDefault instead of Where, I think I am gonna google it later.

Comment: @user6336440 The code by Steve is a shortcut to `db.CodPromocions.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault()`, it is not that you should not use `Where`.

Comment: I am gonna try that one aswell Camilo